# .bat current folder name

Tags: windows, batch-file

In my bat script, I'm calling another script and passing it a string parameter

```
cscript log.vbs "triggered from folder <foldername> by Eric"
```

The string parameter as you can see contains the name of the folder from which the script is being called. What's the right way to pass this dynamically insert this folder name to the script?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want the directory where you're currently at, you can get that from `%cd%`. That's your current working directory.

If you're going to be *changing* your current working directory during the script execution, just save it at the start:

```
set startdir=%cd%
```

then you can use `%startdir%` in your code regardless of any changes later on (which affect `%cd%`).

---

If you just want to get the *last* component of that path (as per your comment), you can use the following as a baseline:

```
    @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
    @echo off
    set startdir=%cd%
    set temp=%startdir%
    set folder=
:loop
    if not "x%temp:~-1%"=="x\" (
        set folder=!temp:~-1!!folder!
        set temp=!temp:~0,-1!
        goto :loop
    )
    echo.startdir = %startdir%
    echo.folder   = %folder%
    endlocal && set folder=%folder%
```

This outputs:

```
    C:\Documents and Settings\Pax> testprog.cmd
    startdir = C:\Documents and Settings\Pax
    folder   = Pax
```

It works by copying the characters from the end of the full path, one at a time, until it finds the `\` separator. It's neither pretty nor efficient, but Windows batch programming rarely is :-)

**EDIT**

Actually, there is a simple and very efficient method to get the last component name.

```
for %%F in ("%cd%") do set "folder=%~nxF"
```

Not an issue for this situation, but if you are dealing with a variable containing a path that may or may not end with `\`, then you can guarantee the correct result by appending `\.`

```
for %%F in ("%pathVar%\.") do set "folder=%~nxF"
```

Comment: @Berming, I've added code which will give you the last component of the path. See the update.

Comment: Just what I needed, thank you very much. I noticed though that when I `endlocal` I can't access the `folder` variable after that, so I took out that line. I figured since I removed that line, I should also remove the `@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion` at the top, but removing that line caused problems, so I kept that one.

Comment: @Berming, see the update. If you leave off the `endlocal`, it will affect you later. You can _still_ use `setlocal/endlocal` to make sure the delayed expansion works but modify the `endlocal` to `endlocal && set folder=%folder%` so that the `folder` variable escapes.

Comment: Learned the hard way that @setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion is really needed

Answer (score 9):

Try %~dp0.

Here: http://weblogs.asp.net/whaggard/archive/2005/01/28/get-directory-path-of-an-executing-batch-file.aspx

Comment: This gives the folder where the bat script is stored, which may or may not be the same as from where the script is being called, so it doesn't work in my case, because almost always it's being called from a different location that's different from where the script is actually stored.

Comment: Right! Sorry. OK, I'll leave this answer here as a reference - someone might find `%~dp0` useful for certain purposes.