# Batch file get present working directory after cd command

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line-interface, working-directory

When I run a batch file that lies in `C:\some\dir` I know I can use `%cd%` and `%~dp0` to get the path of the batch file itself and other information as described [here](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

But I have not managed to get the "present working directory" after the batch file has executed a couple of `cd` commands.

So for example:

- Batch file is in `C:\some\dir`
- Batch file executes `cd sub` and later `cd sub2`

How would I get the path to *that folder*?

It should yield `C:\some\dir\sub\sub2` and would be the equivalent of `pwd` command when doing all of the above manually in the command line!

I had no luck with any of the commands above! It says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3848657/3248285) the `%cd%` variable is supposed to update after `cd` commands are used, but I always get `C:\some\dir` as output.

**EDIT**

[link to a short version of my batch file](http://pastebin.com/N0MwbjUv)

Comment: It's working exactly as you describe that it should, over here...

Comment: Please read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25440709/2861476). Without seeing your code (it is easier if you include it in the question), it seems there could be two options: 1) a problem with delayed expansion or  2) a value directly assigned to the `%cd%` variable masking the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your Batch file does something like this:

```
@echo off
echo Start at: %cd%

cd sub
cd sub2

echo Currently at: %cd%
```

The second `echo` command will show `C:\some\dir\sub\sub2` for sure. However, if the `%cd%` is placed *in a code block*, that is, enclosed in parentheses (like inside an `if` or `for` command), then this is the classical Delayed Expansion problem (as MC ND indicated):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

>log.txt (
   cd sub
   cd sub2

   echo Before this code block the current directory was: %cd%
   echo But currently it is: !cd!
)
```

For further details, look for "delayed expansion".

Comment: I have edited my original question and added a link to my batch file. You were right regarding the **code block / delayed expansion**! `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`and using the `!cd!` command fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**I)** you can preserve the current directory at the begging of the script:

```
@echo off
set "curr_dir=%cd%"
...some cd commands...
cd /d "%curr_dir%"
```

**II)** you can use `pushd/popd` (may be better)...

```
@echo off
....
pushd sub
...some commands...
popd
pushd sub2
...some commands...
popd
```

---

...or like this, if the given sub-directories might not exist:

```
@echo off
....
pushd .
cd /D sub
...some commands...
popd
pushd .
cd /D sub2
...some commands...
popd
```

*Explanation:*
Supposing you successfully pushed `sub` to the directory stack but `sub2` cannot be found so `pushd sub2` fails and nothing is pushed, the next `popd` un-pushes `sub` unintentionally; pushing the current directory `pushd .` however won't ever fail...

[more info](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)

Comment: Regarding I) I'm not trying to go _back_ to the original directory. I'm trying to get the present directory _after_ the cd commands. Will try II) and report back.

Comment: Altough they seem quite useful `pushd` and `popd` did not work in my case.